# Problems scrolling down -Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I have a HP Compaq Tc4400 with 2,5gb RAM with Intel Core Duo T5600 / 1.83 GHz. and I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I can't scroll down with the trackpad. There is a site allowed in the trackpad in the right for scroll down in pages that works in Windows but in Ubuntu when I try it the mouse moves down.

ls -l /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
http://pastebin.com/UWeV9dnm

How can I fix it??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of trackpad is it? Can you post the output of `xinput list`?

Comment: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=10 [slave pointer (2)] @fakedad

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
synclient VertEdgeScroll=1
```

and see if that allows you to scroll by using the right edge of the trackpad.

If it does you can make the change permanent by making the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-synaptics-options.conf` with your favorite editor. For example, with `gedit`:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-synaptics-options.conf
```

Then putting the following in the file

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "touchpad catchall"
  Driver "synaptics"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

  Option "VertEdgeScroll" "1"

EndSection
```

Comment: The permanent method doesn't work. I do it as you said and I restarted Ubuntu and it doesn't work. Thank

Comment: @antonio8909 Does the temporary method work properly?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` on your original question?

Comment: Done @fakedad I posted it in pastebin. (Link in the first post)

Comment: @antonio8909 I'm really not sure why the configuration file wouldn't be working. You could check/post the contents of `50-synaptics.conf`, `50-vmmouse.conf`, and `51-synaptics-quirks.conf` to see if there is anything in there that conflicts with the config in `60-synaptics-options.conf`, but, if I understand the ordering correctly, `60-synaptics-options.conf` should override anything else.

Comment: Here you are @fakedad https://www.mywikis.com/clearcloud/files/antonio8909///synaptic.zip

Comment: Hi @fakedad did you check it? Thanks

Comment: @antonio8909 Yes, I checked the files. I could not seem to find anything unusual. To be completely honest, I have no idea why the method I suggested doesn't work. I tested it, but there very well may be something else going on that prevents it from working for you. I am not sure what the next step towards troubleshooting would be.

Comment: For me, this is a very bad problem. If I can't fix it, I'll delete ubuntu and look for another Linux distro or come back to Windows. Thanks anyway

Comment: @antonio8909 If `synclient VertEdgeScroll=1` works, you could add `synclient VertEdgeScroll=1` to `/etc/rc.local` to make it run on startup. I haven't tested this yet, but it might work.

Comment: @antonio8909 And, of course, add it before the `exit 0`.

Comment: Hi @fakedad I already come back to Windows 10. I'll let you now when I come to Ubuntu again and I'll tell you. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @fakedad I reinstalled Ubuntu and do what you told me synclient etc etc and it doesn't work :(